# How do you determine the effective resistance of a finite grid of resistors?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, passive-networks, resistivity

Disclaimer: I am a geophysicist with limited electrical engineering background. I am not sure if this problem is incredibly easy, incredibly complex, or completely nonsensical.

**My goal: Determine the bulk resistivity of a rock sample using resistor networks.**

The rock sample is to be modelled using a resistor network with certain resistors having high resistance(representing solid rock) and others resistors having low resistance (representing fluid pathways in the rock).

Suppose I have a network of resistors on a uniform grid as shown below. In the example shown, each line segment has an associated resistor labelled 1 through 24 on a 3-by-3 grid. The resistances of each line segment are known.

The total length of the grid is \$L\$ and the "area" is \$A\$ (in this case it is a 2-D example, so the area is also just a length). The bulk resistivity of the sample is then given by:

$$\rho_{bulk} = \frac{R_{eff}A}{L}$$

[image]

**My question: How do I determine the effective resistance, \$R_{eff}\$ of the network?**

I have looked online but all I can find are discussions about *infinite* networks, source and sink currents etc. I am not interested in the current or voltage.

Can this problem be solved as it stands?

Comment: I would plug it into a simulator and let the simulator solve it. You can construct your model as a spice circuit. Then to find resistance, just use Ohm's law (V = I * R). Spice will tell you the current so you can calculate R.

Comment: The whole thing can potentially be automated using command line spice, but for proof of concept, you can enter your circuit in a free spice such as LTSpice. Apply a voltage, and display current. LTspice can also display simple functions such as a voltage divided by a current (resistance).

Comment: Darcy, there are a number of approaches. I'd like to ask a few questions before I offer any thoughts. (1) There is a very easy bit of software you could write. Are you looking for this kind of approach? (2) You could solve this using traditional Nodal Analysis. Are you looking for this kind of approach? (3) Your problem breaks down into *vertices* and *edges*. (Given your geophysicist background, I would expect you know the meaning of those two terms.) How do you, a priori, work out the values you'd plug in for the edges?

Comment: @jonk I would primarily be interested in option (1) to write a short piece of code myself to do this.

I determine the edge resistances based on a priori pore geometry and a known resistivity of a rock mineral or fluid.

Comment: Darcy, there are also techniques that draw from triangulated irregular networks which immediately spring to my mind when you write, "fluid pathways." Have you read anything on that topic? I don't know what your goals ultimately are, but you might want to look these up, too. These would be great to use for gradients helping you understand where "currents" would tend to concentrate. If that's a concern.

Comment: @Darcy Okay. I'll write up a simple answer then. It assumes that you can divide up the length and width by an integer M and N so that the grid is regular. Other than that, the code is quite simple to understand and write.

Comment: There was a question like this a while back that got a lot of answers.  I can't find it right now.  [This is the closest I can find.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19608/how-to-calculate-equivalent-resistance)

Comment: [Another similar one.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/279745/how-to-calculate-the-total-resistance-of-this-electrical-circuit)

Comment: [Still not the one I had in mind.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259534/in-a-grid-of-resistors-does-placement-of-the-voltage-source-affect-the-nodal-re)

Comment: I remember seeing the matrix formula in a geology textbook.  Where is yours?

Comment: The current flowing in rock depends on the mechanical stress in the rock.   To learn more about this weird effect, google Friedman Freund's work at the SETI institute.   If Freund is an alien, he seems to be a legal one, and he has intelligence, so SETI is successful.  Bit I have yet to see a thermodynamic accounting of this effect.

Comment: Your sketch shows wires connected to the middle of resistors in two places.    In modeling these grids, we electrical engineers only connect wires to the circuit nodes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The basic idea is fairly simple. You arrange a matrix (\$V\$) that represents "nodes" or vertices in your system. Each of these nodes has a scalar-valued "voltage" associated with it that can be changed or updated as the algorithm proceeds. There will also be two nodes whose voltage cannot be changed. We are going to apply a "battery" of sorts here, so those two nodes represent the two ends of this battery.

Separately, another two matrices (\$Rv\$ and \$Rh\$) represents the edges in the system, horizontal and vertical. These are your resistance values, I guess. I'm not sure how you intend on filling these out. But that's your problem. This technique assumes you are able to populate these matrices, as well.

Depending upon the computer language you use, you may or may not be able to use negative indices. Doesn't matter. It's just a matter of keeping in mind what you are faced with.

Let's assume length \$L\$ is divided into \$N_L\$ sections and that "length" \$A\$ is divided into \$N_A\$ sections. Then you will need to construct a matrix with \$\left(N_L+1\right)\cdot\left(N_A+1\right)\$ vertices for the scalar voltage values. (or larger.) You will also need those other two matrices with \$N_A\cdot\left(N_L+1\right)\$ vertical edges and \$N_L\cdot\left(N_A+1\right)\$ horizontal edges between those vertices.

Now. Initialize all of the vertices with \$0\:\textrm{V}\$. Choose one of the vertices on the left (in the middle, preferably) and note it as a \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ value that is NOT allowed to ever change. Use whatever method you want for this. Choose one of the vertices on the right (in the middle, preferably) and change its value to \$1\:\textrm{V}\$, while again taking note that its value is NOT allowed to ever change. A technique that works here is to simply let it change normally but then replace the value each and every step. But it doesn't matter how you achieve this, so long as you do achieve it.

(There are other techniques for efficiency reasons. But it's probably not worth bothering with them here.)

Now for the algorithm, which is sometimes called a *checkerboard* or *red-black* algorithm. Moving through your node voltage matrix, process each node where the sum of the two indices, \$i+j\$ is even, performing the following simple assignment:

$$\begin{align*}
V_{i,j}&=\frac{Rh_{i,j-1}\cdot Rh_{i,j}\cdot\left(V_{i-1,j}\cdot  Rv_{i,j}+V_{i+1,j}\cdot Rv_{i-1,j}\right)}{Rh_{i,j-1}\cdot Rh_{i,j}\cdot \left(Rv_{i,j}+Rv_{i-1,j}\right)+Rv_{i-1,j}\cdot Rv_{i,j}\left(Rh_{i,j}+Rh_{i,j-1}\right)}\\\\
&+\frac{Rv_{i-1,j}\cdot Rv_{i,j}\cdot \left(V_{i,j-1}\cdot  Rh_{i,j}+V_{i,j+1}\cdot Rh_{i,j-1}\right)}{Rh_{i,j-1}\cdot Rh_{i,j}\cdot \left(Rv_{i,j}+Rv_{i-1,j}\right)+Rv_{i-1,j}\cdot Rv_{i,j}\left(Rh_{i,j}+Rh_{i,j-1}\right)}
\end{align*}$$

The above equation is nothing more than computing the voltage of a central node having four resistors connecting to it, where the voltages at the other ends of the four resistors are known. The central node voltage is then computed from the above equation. Since the divisor is the same for each term, you could just compute the sum of the numerators and then divide once by the denominator.

That will update all the nodes where the sum \$i+j\$ is even. Now you perform the same procedure to all of the nodes where the sum \$i+j\$ is odd. Once both these steps has been performed, you have completed one cycle.

If necessary, reset the special two nodes (for \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ and for \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ as earlier discussed.) Or, if you protected those two nodes, there's no need to reset them.

You are ready for the next cycle. Perform these cycles as many times as you feel is necessary for the overall state to settle down (and it will.)

When you stop the process, you can easily work out the resistance by either choosing to look at the nodes surrounding your left-side protected node or else look at the nodes surrounding your right-side protected node. (It may be a good idea to make your matrix just enough larger [by 1 in all directions] so that you will actually have four nodes surrounding either choice.) The difference in voltages between the surrounding nodes and the special node, divided by the resistance in the edges between them tells you the current leaving/entering your special node. Since this is a "battery" node, this current must be ALL of the current. Since the voltage is \$1\:\textrm{V}\$, by definition, dividing 1 by the sum of these four currents you find tells you the total resistance.

I'm staring at some code I wrote that totals, with lots of comments, just 67 lines. So it's NOT hard to write.

The "short summary" of this idea is that you apply a \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ battery and then watch as the voltages spread throughout the system. Once the voltages stabilize (your criteria for that), all you have to do is look at the current coming into, or out of, one battery terminal or the other one. They should both be the same current value (within some numerical bounds) for obvious reasons.

---

> Why is it that you must separate the system into i+j = even and i+j =
>   odd?

Suppose you compute \$V_{5,5}=f\left(V_{4,5},V_{6,5},V_{5,4},V_{5,6}\right)\$. This references the nodes that surround \$V_{5,5}\$. That's fine. Suppose you next compute \$V_{5,6}=f\left(V_{4,6},V_{6,6},V_{5,5},V_{5,7}\right)\$. Note that in the list of parameters is the value you just computed for \$V_{5,5}\$? This would "smudge" things a lot. It's not sound. Instead, each cycle of odd/even should "appear as if" it occurred at the same moment. So your next computation should be \$V_{5,7}=f\left(V_{4,7},V_{6,7},V_{5,6},V_{5,8}\right)\$ because none of the inputs to the function are nodes that were changed ***during*** this step. Then you swing around and compute the alternates, avoiding the smudging but now updating the alternates. You really do have to do it this way.

> Also, is the formula identical for both even and odd steps through?

Yes, it's the same.

> Can it all be solved in one step using some sort of linear system Ax=b
>   where A is a linear operator and b provides the boundary conditions?
>   Looking at it, it seems somewhat analogous to finite difference
>   methods for solving partial differential equations..

There is a connection. I think it's called a 'matrix-free' implementation.

---

Here's an example. The following set of resistor values were placed into LTSpice for simulation:

[image]

I kept it short and simple. As you can see, the approximate computed current from the \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ power supply is given as \$30.225\:\textrm{mA}\$. (The actual value computed by Spice was \$30.224552\:\textrm{mA}\$.)

I ran the following VB.NET program:

```
Module GEOGRID

    Const NL As Integer = 2
    Const NA As Integer = 2
    Const INF As Double = 1.0E+32

    Sub Main()

        Static Rh As Double(,) = New Double(NL + 2, NA + 1) {
                    {INF, INF, INF, INF},
                    {INF, 5, 21, INF},
                    {INF, 76, 10, INF},
                    {INF, 32, 22, INF},
                    {INF, INF, INF, INF}}
        Static Rv As Double(,) = New Double(NA + 1, NL + 2) {
                    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF},
                    {INF, 61, 50, 16, INF},
                    {INF, 56, 45, 18, INF},
                    {INF, INF, INF, INF, INF}}
        Dim V As Double(,) = New Double(NL + 2, NA + 2) {
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
        Dim PDE As Func(Of Integer, Integer, Double) = Function(ByVal i As Integer, ByVal j As Integer) (
                    Rh(i, j - 1) * Rh(i, j) * (V(i - 1, j) * Rv(i, j) + V(i + 1, j) * Rv(i - 1, j)) +
                    Rv(i - 1, j) * Rv(i, j) * (V(i, j - 1) * Rh(i, j) + V(i, j + 1) * Rh(i, j - 1))
                  ) / (
                    Rh(i, j - 1) * Rh(i, j) * (Rv(i, j) + Rv(i - 1, j)) +
                    Rv(i - 1, j) * Rv(i, j) * (Rh(i, j) + Rh(i, j - 1))
                  )
        Dim IV As Func(Of Integer, Integer, Double) = Function(ByVal i As Integer, ByVal j As Integer) 0 +
                    (V(i, j) - V(i - 1, j)) / Rv(i - 1, j) + (V(i, j) - V(i + 1, j)) / Rv(i, j) +
                    (V(i, j) - V(i, j - 1)) / Rh(i, j - 1) + (V(i, j) - V(i, j + 1)) / Rh(i, j)
        Dim idx As Integer = NA \ 2 + 1
        Dim jdx1 As Integer = NL + 1
        Dim jdx2 As Integer = 1
        For x As Integer = 1 To 1000
            For k As Integer = 0 To (NA + 1) * (NL + 1) - 1 Step 2
                Dim i As Integer = k \ (NL + 1)
                Dim j As Integer = k - i * (NL + 1) + 1
                i += 1
                If Not (i = idx AndAlso (j = jdx1 OrElse j = jdx2)) Then V(i, j) = PDE(i, j)
            Next
            For k As Integer = 1 To (NA + 1) * (NL + 1) - 1 Step 2
                Dim i As Integer = k \ (NL + 1)
                Dim j As Integer = k - i * (NL + 1) + 1
                i += 1
                If Not (i = idx AndAlso (j = jdx1 OrElse j = jdx2)) Then V(i, j) = PDE(i, j)
            Next
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("R = " & (1.0 / IV(idx, jdx1)).ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("R = " & (-1.0 / IV(idx, jdx2)).ToString)
    End Sub

End Module
```

With the following result printed out: \$R = 33.0856844038614\:\Omega\$. Which is the correct answer.

The above program shows a way of setting up the resistors, vertical and horizontal, as well as the voltage matrix, so that it simplifies some of the tests for non-existent nodes and/or resistor values. The code is a little cleaner, this way, though it does require some more array elements. (I've simply made the extra resistor values infinite in value.) Just compare how I've set up the arrays with the way the schematic was laid out, as well, and I think you will be able to work out all the exact details here.

I've also hacked in the resistors and node values, of course, without making this in any way a general purpose program for reading up a table of values. But that generality is pretty easy to add. And this code should make everything I wrote absolutely unambiguous.

Note that I also just ran the \$x\$ loop 1000 types, alternating red and black within the \$x\$ loop. I just picked a number. To make this more general purpose, you may prefer a different way of determining how many iterations to perform.

And a final note. Just to prove that you can use either fixed voltage node's current to compute the resistor, I've used two lines in order to print out both values: one computed from the \$0\:\textrm{V}\$ side and one computed from the \$1\:\textrm{V}\$ side. Either way, you should see the same number.

(Okay. One more final note. This would be much better targeted at F# or any decent compiler targeting a massively parallel computing system. Each calculation in either "red" or "black" can be performed in parallel; completely independently of each other. F# makes this trivial. So coded in F#, you could run this on all of your available cores without anything special to do. It just works. Just a note in case you are collecting a LOT of data in some fashion and might want to take full advantage of a multi-core system.)

---

***END NOTE:***

The derivation is pretty simple from KCL. Place four resistors into the following arrangement:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmuEjfm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Apply KCL:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V}{R_1}+\frac{V}{R_2}+\frac{V}{R_3}+\frac{V}{R_4} &= \frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_3}+\frac{V_4}{R_4}\\\\
&\therefore\\\\
V &=\left(\frac{V_1}{R_1}+\frac{V_2}{R_2}+\frac{V_3}{R_3}+\frac{V_4}{R_4}\right)\bigg(R_1 \mid\mid R_2 \mid\mid R_3 \mid\mid R_4\bigg)
\end{align*}$$

Some playing around with algebra gets the result I used in the code.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I have a few clarifying questions.


1) Why is it that you must separate the system into \$i+j\$ = even and \$i+j\$ = odd?


2) Can it all be solved in one step using some sort of linear system \$\mathrm{Ax}=\mathrm{b}\$ where \$\mathrm{A}\$ is a linear operator and \$\mathrm{b}\$ provides the boundary conditions? Looking at it, it seems somewhat analogous to finite difference methods for solving partial differential equations...

Comment: Also, is the formula identical for both even and odd steps through?

Comment: @Darcy I'll write a little more to help cover these issues.

Comment: Thanks again for the details. One final question (and maybe this could go as an entirely separate question but I will ask it here): if all the resistors in the network have the same resistance (say 1 Ohm), then does it follow that the effective resistance should also be 1 Ohm? My intuition says that it should, but I am not sure.

Comment: I've coded up the problem in MATLAB for the simple 2x2 system you've shown above. I get the same answer as you, which is encouraging. If I set all the resistors to have a value of 1 Ohm then when I run my program, the effective resistance is also 1 Ohm. This matches what my intuition would suggest.

However, when I go to a 3x3 or 4x4 system, my intuition no longer holds. For a 4x4 system with uniform 1 Ohm resistors, I end up with an effective resistance of 1.3636 Ohm. Is this a bug or is my intuition just wrong?

Comment: @Darcy Your intuition is wrong and the MATLAB result is correct.

Comment: @Darcy In case it helps, this link provides a useful discussion also dealing with finite grids: [Infinite Grid of Resistors](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm). It should address your intuition, though. My own intuition would tend to approach the problem differently. As the grid becomes infinitely finer, there would be a single conductance path through the middle, plus pairs of just slightly lower conductance on either side (elliptical shaped paths), growing out to a full circle. I'd neglect the difference of a square vs circle in this. But PI would certainly present itself.

Comment: Can you provide a source for where you got the checkerboard equation? I am assuming it is using KCL or something? I am failing to see how you derived it. Nvm: I got it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis

Comment: @Darcy Yes, I derived it on the spot from KCL, by hand, just for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly take the approach of a 2D resistor network to model a 2D problem but that can get somewhat tricky when moving to 3 dimensions. You might want to consider using a more traditional (these days) approach with volume conductors defined in your domains with an appropriate conductivity assigned to each. The FEMM freeware code (http://www.femm.info/wiki/HomePage) is very capable and can be used for 2D, axial symmetry and 3D. From there you can consider moving to much more capable codes like SCIrun (https://www.sci.utah.edu/) which is an academic code for volume conductor problems of substantial complexity. I use it routinely for meshes of more than a million tetrahedrons. Even though it was primarily developed for biological modeling it should work great for what you are doing. The examples of forward problems in the forward/inverse toolkit should get you going. You might find the inverse problems valuable for impedance tomography, too. I generally use version 4 since version 5 is still a work in progress. The software also has an interface to tetgen which is a great mesh building code.

Finally, if you are not opposed to spending money there is always COMSOL, which is very easy to use (and quite expensive).

Answer (score 0):

> I am not interested in the current or voltage.

You *are* interested in it. Resistance is just the ratio of current to voltage, assuming that you have solution for current for some external voltage. And you could solve it using any SPICE package directly.

This approach to determining resistance has a caveat: it needs a linear system. Anything with capacitors, inductors and resistors as the only elements would be such a system. Otherwise, the resistance becomes a function of the voltage applied and potentially also of the history of the circuit, and is better called incremental or differential resistance.