# Calculate equivalent resistance of the circuit

Tags: voltage, current, resistors, resistance

[image]

I am really confused with the above problem.

Each side represents a resistance R. How should I calculate resistance in case of infinite resistances.

Comment: This is a classic puzzle. If you google 'infinite resistor grid' you will find many detailed answers

Comment: Ah. The infamous [xkcd 356](https://xkcd.com/356/) problem. Here's a way to numerically approximate it: [VB.NET program to solve any finite resistor grid](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342340/how-do-you-determine-the-effective-resistance-of-a-finite-grid-of-resistors/342358#342358). Google hits this one [every time](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm) for some math work.

Comment: @Electro_Woog, I read somewhere that it is impossible to solve this. Is this true?

Comment: *impossible to solve this* If you want an **exact** answer then indeed you will probably not get it. As more resistors are added the influence of these extra resistors on the answer will be smaller and smaller. So in my opinion the answer is really a limit function.

Comment: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm ....not easy at all as it seems lol