# Compute electric field in complex 3D geometry

Tags: simulation, matlab, python

I have a CAD file with a pretty complex geometry. I would like to compute the electric field generated by this geometry when a specific charge density is defined.

I guess I will have to go through some *finite elements* algorithms (which I have no experience at all, so any suggestions for tutorials and literature is more than welcome)

Could you suggest some toolboxes to simulate the electric field, or more in general to solve partial differential equations, in a complex geometry.

It is not a requirement, but I prefer to use Python or MATLAB as programming languages.

Comment: PDEs are easy, if you don't care about efficiency. You can set up any initial conditions you want and then just iterate using a "checkerboard" pattern of red and black squares. Read what I wrote [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/342358/38098) as it may provide some ideas for you. I've used similar techniques for very complex structures involving how charges reach steady state as they distrubute throughout them. Coding was dead-easy. Run time was... longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Quickfield](https://quickfield.com/) is useful to you.
It is a finite element analysis software package running on Windows platforms which does computer simulations of electromagnetic fields.
You can import CAD drawings.

Comment: thank you! Quickfield seems it can do the job!